# Cannot alter file permission on server (550). Is this because I have no domain name?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver, ftp, modx

I am building a site on a CMS (modx) for a client who has not decided on their domain name. I have access to WHM so just set up an account with out pointing any domain name to it and began developing just using the URL

`http://example.com/~newsite`

Everything seemed to be going well until I installed TinyMCE (the WYSIWYG text editor) which allows you to browse and upload images on the server and add them to page content. The editor worked fine but I just couldn't access any files on the web server.

Looking into the issue I saw that many files that were part of TinyMCE were non executalbe (644). I tried changing them but got a 550 error, eg:

`550 Could not change perms on jquery-1.4.2.js: Operation not permitted`

Could this be something to do with the way I am accessing the files on FTP? I am using the hosting servers IP address as the host, rather than a hostname.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you can't access any files on the server, then how is TinyMCE working fine? Also, TinyMCE is a JavaScript text editor. There's no reason for any of those files to be executable on the server.

Comment: Note that if you are accessing the site via `http://example.com/~newsite/`, as opposed to `http://realdomain.com/` then any root-relative client-side URLs are going to be referring to 1-folder level above the web root. You are better off setting some temporary domain.

Answer (score 1):

A [550 FTP error](http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WS-20000817-DM02.htm) means you don't have permission to perform a particular operation (write to a directory, modify a file, delete a file, change the permissions on a file, etc.). It has nothing to do with whether your files reside directly in the webroot of a domain or if it's under a subdirectory.

Comment: Comming back to this: Are you saying it would work if I changed the parent directories permissions?

Comment: You might actually find out what the safe file permissions should be in real life before changing them. Most combined php/javascript applications do not set execution on more than about 4 or 5 files. See comment from @w3d on your question.